# Complete mismatch of font display in Google Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: html, css, font-face

I've used a CSS from Goolge and I'm getting puzzling result. Below are two screenshots. The one from Firefox shows the correct (or, at least, the expected rendering), the one from Chrome shows some random font...

[image]
*Firefox*

[image]
*Chrome*

This is how I load it:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic'
          rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

The relevant CSS rule:

```
.digit {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive;
    font-size: 24pt;
    background-color: #d1d2d4;
    color: #ebebec;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left
}
```

I'm at a loss...

Comment: Is the font actually being loaded by chrome? Looks like it is falling back to cursive to me.

Comment: I've had some weird issues between FF and Chr with Google Fonts (directly linking). I usually have more luck with consistency by downloading the font and using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate a locally-linked version.

Comment: Firefox is notorious for not liking cross-domain fonts, but you seem to have the inverse problem. Check that the files are loading in Chrome. You may have to fix headers to get Chrome to accept them.

Comment: That's strange, never had an issue with Google fonts since (I believe) they are all Create Commons (or similar) licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Following, somewhat, Fluidbyte's advice I decided to use the font file I have, rather than the one from Google's CDN and it worked. I'd still be interested to know why wouldn't it work the first time I tried, but as the practical solution (possibly only relevant to this particular font) this should help you, if you are facing the same problem.